# Making inotifywait to watch for symlinks

Tags: linux, shell, filesystemwatcher

I'm searching a way to notify a hierarchy for modifications but I have symlinks and I want a distinct notification for every symlink that point on the modified file.

A trick can be to find them using a find but I prefer something cleaner :)

Comment: How frequently do the actual symlinks (not the real files) change?  eg Do they stay static through a day?

Answer (score 0):

I came to something like this, it works, but i don't like it :

```
for f in $(find -L $SOURCE_DIR -samefile "$folder$file")
do
    if [ -L "$f" ]
    then
        do_something_with_the_link $(dirname "$f")/ $(basename "$f")
    fi
done
```